# No message matching on assert_push using phoenix channels

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

```
     No message matching %Phoenix.Socket.Message{event: "initialize", payload: %{new_player: ^new_player, ref: nil, topic: "game:subtopic"}} after 100ms.
 The following variables were pinned:
   new_player = %Player.State{hp: %{current: 10, max: 10}, position: %{target_x: 0, target_z: 0, x: 0, z: 0}, socket_id: "user_id", username: nil}
 Process mailbox:
   %Phoenix.Socket.Message{event: "initialize", join_ref: 714, payload: %{new_player: %Player.State{hp: %{current: 10, max: 10}, position: %{target_x: 0, target_z: 0, x: 0, z: 0}, socket_id: "user_id", username: nil}}, ref: nil, topic: "game:subtopic"}
```

The code from the test:

```
new_player = World.player_state(socket.id)

assert_push "initialize",
            %{new_player: ^new_player, ref: nil, topic: "game:subtopic"},
            100
```

I'm not sure why the test if failing. I tried not pinning the new player. The only difference I see is `join_ref` isn't a part of the struct returned in my test.

I don't understand!

Comment: Oh it may be that I am using a struct in the test! Oops.

Answer (score 0):

The two following fields are actually not part of the `payload` but of the `Phoenix.Socket.Message`, which is why it is not matching I believe: `ref: nil, topic: "game:subtopic"`.

If you remove those two it should match.